# Raster to ASCII - adding processing multiple files piece of code in Python

Tags: python, batch-file, ascii, arcgis, raster

I wrote a piece of code in python that converts a raster file to ascii. Now, I need to make it handle possibly all files in the folder. Also, at the end save ascii files with the same name that the original with a suffix added.
I am a total newbee in python and i promise i did my homework, i could just not make the batch processing work on my own. Any help will be so much appreciated!!

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/Data"
inRaster = ("test.img")
outASCII = "c:/output/test3.asc"
arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion(inRaster, outASCII)
```

Comment: if you already work with python you don't need to pay expansive license fees to ArcGIS, check out GDAL.org they have excellent python bindings, and you can very easily convert binary raster to ascii.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import os
dir_name = ...
for filename in os.listdir(dir_name):
    if not filename.endswith(".img"): continue
    full_path = os.path.join(dir_name, filename)
    outASCII = '%s.asc' % (full_path,)
    arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion(full_path, outASCII)
```

It gets all the filenames ending in `.img` in the directory `dir_name` and passes it to your conversion function.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'c:/data'

listOfImgs = arcpy.ListRasters('*.img')
for imageFile in listOfImgs:
    outASCII = '%s.asc' % (imageFile,)
    arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion(imageFile, outASCII)
```